# Sharpness of Gaussian function

Tags: calculus

Consider the gaussian distribution (I'm wrestling with an explanation given in my physics book from which this equation comes from),

$$g(N,s) = g(N,0)e^{-2s^2/N}$$

where
$$ g(N,0) = \Big(\frac{2}{\pi N}\Big)^{1/2}2^N$$

$g$ is reduced to $e^{-1}$ of its maximum value at (given N constant. It's the number of particles if you're wondering) $s_0^2 = N/2$. In other words,
$$s_0/N = \Big(\frac{1}{2N}\Big)^{1/2}$$
is when $g$ is $1/e$ of its initial value. This value is taken as a reasonable measure of the fractional width of the distribution. When $N \approx 10^{22}$, the fractional width is of the order $10^{-11}$. My question is, how does the last equation measure the sharpness of the gaussian distribution? As $N \rightarrow \infty$, I see how the fractional width tends to zero since $N$ is in the denominator. So the peak around $s = 0$ becomes sharper. However, I'd like to see that the $s$ where $g$ is $1/e$ of its initial value goes to zero because that point on the graph I can imagine. I don't know what $s_0/N$ really is graphically. So looking at 
$$s_0^2 = N/2$$
If $N \rightarrow \infty$, then $s_0^2 \rightarrow \infty$ which is not zero. Now looking at the gaussian function, I plug $s = s_0$ and let $N \rightarrow \infty$.The term in the exponent is $-2s^2/N$, so there is an extra $N$ that might compete with the $N$ in $s_0$. But I'm getting nowhere.

Anyways, I'd like to somehow see that $s_0$ goes to zero as $N$ gets large. My book says that the function becomes sharply peaked in this limit and use the fractional width to demonstrate this. I don't know what this fractional width is graphically. It just seems like they decided to divide $s_0$ by $N$. I'd like to see that the peak gets narrower with $s_0$ going to zero.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you mean. In the penultimate paragraph you write, "If $N \to \infty$ then $s_0^2 \to \infty$ which is not zero" (all of which is correct) but in the last paragraph you write, "I'd like to somehow see that $s_0$ goes to zero as $N$ gets large."

Comment: @Travis Maybe this will clear up. Thinking of the distribution, I imagine the point $s=s_0$. To see that the graph becomes sharply peaked (small width) in the limit that $N$ gets large, I imagine the point $s_0$ going to zero. If the distribution is sharply peaked or narrow, it should have a small $s_0$. My book  uses $s_0/N$ to show that the function is narrow in the large $N$ limit. They call this term the fractional width. However this number doesn't mean anything to mean. I'd like to demonstrate small width by small $s_0$

Comment: As $N \to \infty$, the graph becomes wider, not narrower. It's the relative (fractional) width $s_0 / N$ that becomes narrower: As $N \to \infty$, the distribution becomes more and more concentrated around the mean, *relative to the size of $N$*.

Comment: Think of it this way: If you flip $2^3$ coins, it's typical but not overwhelmingly likely ($p = 91/128$) that they the number of heads is within half the mean (in this case $2$) of the mean, $4$. But if you flip $2^{20} \approx 10^6$ coins, most of the time the total number of heads *won't* be within $2$ of the mean (i.e., in the range $[2^{20} - 2, 2^{20} + 2]$, but it's *almost certain* that the total number of heads will be within half the mean (within $2^{19}$) of the mean (in this case, in the range $[2^{20} - 2^{19}, 2^{20} + 2^{19}]$).